# phpMyAdmin - configure to log in remotely

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've recently set up XAMPP on Windows 10 for use by high school student in a first year web development course. They each have their own private database in MySQL and I want them to be able to log into phpMyAdmin to access their databases. None of them will be on the server machine. I also want to be able to log in remotely as root. I've done a great deal of googling and played with config.inc.php a lot. So far, I've configed in a way that root is logged in automatically from everywhere; and changed that so that things work well locally but remotely I get

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

That's where I am now.

Goal: 
1. Allow access and force login from any computer in the world.
2. Allow logout
3. Log out automatically on timeout (and when browser closes if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want the [cookie auth_type](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_auth_type) for this use case. I believe XAMPP uses `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';` by default, which means you're automatically logged in as whichever user is hardcoded in to config.inc.php. Using 'cookie' allows your students to each enter their login credentials and log out as needed.

Further, I believe XAMPP sets up restrictions in Apache to not allow remote connections to phpMyAdmin, so you'll have to edit the Apache configuration file that defines phpMyAdmin access in order to allow access from external connections.

I assume you've already got the computer exposed to the internet and configured with DNS so that it's reachable from the internet? You'll need to set your firewall and/or router to allow incoming connections to the server, of course.